# Perfect forwarding variadic template parameters to member function

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, perfect-forwarding

I am trying to implement the observer pattern with example usage as follows:

```
class Widget
{
    class WidgetObserver
    {
        virtual void SomethingHappened(Widget&) { };
        virtual void TextChanged(Widget&, const char*) { };
        virtual void BoundsChanged(Widget&, const Rect&) { };
    }

    void AddObserver(WidgetObserver& observer)
    {
        observers.Add(observer);
    }

    virtual void OnSomthingHappened()
    {
        observers.Fire(&WidgetObserver::SomethingHappened, *this);
    }

    virtual void OnTextChanged(const char* text)
    {
        observers.Fire(&WidgetObserver::TextChanged, *this, text);
    }

    // Same for OnBoundsChanged(const Rect&)

    ObserverList<Widget> observers;
}

class AnotherWidget : WidgetObserver
{
    virtual void SomethingHappened(Widget& widget) override
    {
         std::cout << "Something happened with " widget.name() << std::endl;
    }

    // Implementations for TextChanged and BoundsChanged ...
}

void main()
{
    Widget w;
    AnotherWidget aw;
    w.AddObserver(aw);
    w.OnSomethingHappened();
}
```

Now my current (partial) implementation of `ObserverList` is:

```
template <typename TObserver>
class ObserverList
{
    std::vector<TObserver*> observer_list;

    void AddObserver(TObserver& observer) { observer_list.push_back(&observer); }

    template <typename ...TArgs>
    void Fire(void(TObserver::*func)(TArgs...), TArgs&& args)
    {
         for (TObserver* ob : observer_list)
         {
             (ob->*func)(std::forward<TArgs>(args)...);
         }
    }
}
```

This works as expected with the functions `SomethingHappened` and `BoundsChanged` which both passes all its parameters by reference rather than by value, but with `TextChanged` one of its parameters (`const char* text`) is passed by value rather than reference. When I changed this to `const char*& text` it compiles but as is it doesn't compile with MSVC++ 14.1 (Visual Studio 2017)

```
error C2672: 'ObserverList<Widget::WidgetObserver>::Fire': no matching overloaded function found
error C2782: 'void ObserverList<Widget::WidgetObserver>::Fire(void (__thiscall Widget::WidgetObserver::* )(TArgs...),TArgs &&...)': template parameter 'TArgs' is ambiguous
```

Seems like the compiler doesn't like parameters passed by value, is there any way to make it like them?

Comment: @xskxzr seems to work and compile! Should I post the answer or will you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare `func` to have a simple type `F`, i.e.

```
template <typename F, typename ...TArgs> 
void Fire(F func, TArgs&&... args);
```